# R: Convert frequency to percentage with only a selected number of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to convert a dataframe filled with frequencies into a dataframe filled with percentage by row using dplyr.

My data set has the particularity to get filled with others variables and I just want to calculate the percentage for a set of columns defined by a vector of names. Plus, I want to use the dplyr library.

```
sim_dat <- function() abs(floor(rnorm(26)*10))
df <- data.frame(a = letters, b = sim_dat(), c = sim_dat(), d = sim_dat()
                 , z = LETTERS)
names_to_transform <- names(df)[2:4]

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(sum_freq_codpos = rowSums(.[names_to_transform])) %>%
  mutate_each(function(x) x / sum_freq_codpos, names_to_transform)
# does not work
```

Any idea on how to do it? I have tried with mutate_at and mutate_each but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're almost there!:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(sum_freq_codpos = rowSums(.[names_to_transform])) %>%
  mutate_at(names_to_transform, funs(./sum_freq_codpos))
```

the dot `.` roughly translates to "the object i am manipulating here", which in this call is "the focal variable in names_to_transform".